# Android Room query with json map?

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I am using Gson library to convert Map with TypeConverter and Room to save it to database.

```
data class Chat(
    val memberIds: Map<String, Boolean>? = null,
)

@JvmStatic
@TypeConverter
fun mapToString(map: Map<String, Boolean>): String? {
    return gson.toJson(map)
}
```

How can I query database based on memberIds field?

I don't even know what should I ask google to search for an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Same here, looking for answer...